# Can I limit the amount of documents a user can download in a given time

Tags: security, sharepoint, download, drm

My company would like to be able to limit the number of documents a user can download over a given period of time. Is this possible in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

OOTB i wouldn't say it is..... however you possibly could write some custom code to do so.

You could essentially rip off the Download a copy ECB menu item and then add some custom code to do some checking against a list or custom DB with the relavent information about the number of downloads and a timestamp and user info.

You could then display an error to the user if required.

You would be creating a new ECB button however you would be able to hide/remove the other one and you could target this to specific lists.

Hope this gives you some sort of starting point.

Cheers
Truez